# How to change order status after form submission in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using the "Forminator" form plugin to handle refund requests for WooCommerce orders
with the following snippet:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'sww_add_account_refund_order_action', 9999, 2 ); 
function sww_add_account_refund_order_action( $actions, $order ) {

   if ( $order->has_status ( 'delivered' ) ) {
    $actions['refund_request'] = array(
        'url'  => sww_get_order_refund_request_url( $order ),
        'name' => __( 'Request Refund', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
}

return $actions;
}
function sww_get_order_refund_request_url( $order ) {

// enter the ID for your page that contains the refund request form
$page_id = 1737;

// now we'll build the right refund URL from it
$refund_url = trailingslashit( get_page_link( $page_id ) ) . '?order=' . $order->get_order_number();
$products   = array();

foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
    if ( $product = wc_get_product( $item['product_id'] ) ) {
        $products[] = $product->get_title();
    }
}

if ( ! empty( $products ) ) {
    $refund_url .= '&products=' . urlencode( implode( ', ', $products ) );
}

return $refund_url;
}
```

The form fetches the order number and the items from the URL and populates them in the fields.
I want the order status to be changed after the form submission, from "Delivered" to "Refund request" (which I already registered in a separate snippet).
I found the Forminator's hooks that trigger after form submission, but I didn't know how and where to use them.

```
do_action( 'forminator_custom_form_after_handle_submit', $form_id, $response );
do_action( 'forminator_custom_form_after_save_entry', $form_id, $response, 'submit' );
```

The first one will trigger if the Submission Behaviour is> Method to Page Reload
and the second one will trigger if the Submission Behaviour is> Method to Ajax, which is set to active.

If it's not possible, please tell me another way to handle refund requests.
Thank you.

Comment: What is in `$response` variable after submission? Nobody can guess by magic how is made your form and what it does return after submission.